# jQuery / AJAX / JSON errors on new server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This question straddles both programming and server issues, not sure it is 100% for serverfault. Here it goes:

I just migrated my Codeigniter (PHP 5.1.2) web app to a new server. In the old server, everything worked normally.

In the new server, all jQuery Ajax is broken, and I've noticed errors affect exclusively Ajax that uses `json` data.

The errors on Firebug show as

```
data is null //data is a json string returned by the server
    if (data.success == 1) {
```

and on Chrome console the same error shows as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of null
```

A few details about the new server:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux
- Plesk 9
- PHP is enabled via Plesk interface - the setting is 'Run PHP as Fast CGI, safe_mode off'
- It has a firewall that is not causing any obvious problems
- .htaccess is currently very lean

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=EmulateIE8"

  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
          BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
          BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
          BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
          BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
      </IfModule>
      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
          Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
      </IfModule>
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|ico|gif|png|flv|pdf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2700"
  </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
  ```

**In addition:**

- one part of the webapp uses jQuery FullCalendar - before the migration it worked perfectly - now I get a blank page (no errors on console - but it uses several JSON strings to populate calendar events
- login using Facebook and Google credentials is broken leading to blank pages (not sure of JSON strings here).

I've tried changing `json` to `jsonp` as suggested elswhere on SO, but this didn't solve the problem. Is any other change to the code required?

Thanks for reading -- any suggestions how to begin troubleshooting this?

Comment: Is there another PHP version installed on your new server? Do you see the PHP script hetting called (e.g. echoing something there)

Comment: PHP is enabled via Plesk interface - the setting is 'Run PHP as Fast CGI, safe_mode off' -- does this answer the question?

Comment: I was talking about PHP version

Comment: Do you mean 'can I install another version?' or 'are there 2 versions installed'? Sorry... :p

Comment: Start from installing Firebug.

Comment: @peter - i am using firebug, see OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by upgrading my PHP version from 5.1.2 (the default install for Plesk 9.5) to PHP 5.3.x.

http://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/PHP

The problem was probably due to my using `json_encode`, which is a PHP > 5.2 function.

Hope this helps anyone out there with similar issues.